# How to run two external scripts simultaneously and get notified when both are done

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the following script to run an external script:

```
with open( 'blah.txt', 'w' ) as f:
    subprocess.call( [ 'exec1', 'param1' ], stdout=f, stderr=f )
```

Question> I need to run two scripts(i.e. exec1 and exec2) at the same time and each write to a different files. I also want to know when both scripts have finished the execution. Is there a good way to do this in python?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but how about this: create two child [threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#thread-objects), one for each script. Each thread creates a [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) object for its script, then calls `my_popen_instance.wait()` so the thread lives until the script finishes executing. The main thread calls `join` on each child thread in turn. Once all `join`s are finished, you know that all scripts have finished execution, and you can continue with your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen

f1 = open( 'blah.txt', 'w' )
f2 = open( 'other_blah.txt', 'w' )
proc1 = Popen([ 'exec1', 'param1' ], stdout=f1, stderr=f1)
proc2 = Popen([ 'exec2', 'param2' ], stdout=f2, stderr=f2)

# If you don't need to be doing anything else, wait for both to finish
proc1.wait()
proc2.wait()

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Heed the usual warnings about `wait()` if you're dealing with `subprocess.PIPE` for either stdin or stdout - if you have to worry about that eventually, you may consider moving to a loop that uses `poll()` to check on the two processes periodically.